# Shell loading issue - bash: /root/.bash_profile: Permission denied

Tags: shell, rhel, login

I am trying to login with regular user over ssh. User login successfully. But user bash not loaded properly. I am getting the below message on my login screen

```
Last login: Mon Jul 27 01:12:45 2020 from xx.xxxx.xxxx
-bash: /root/.bash_profile: Permission denied
-bash-4.2$
```

How can I solve this problem? Also I want to know what is the relation between regular user login with super user `/root/.bash_profile`

Comment: Something your regular user is processing is trying to source `/root/.bash_profile`.  A regular user can't access that file.

Comment: I am also facing  E138: Can't write viminfo file /root/.viminfo!  issue  when regular user try to write any  file with vim editior

Comment: @AndyDalton I want to know the root cause why regular user is trying to source /root/.bash_profile

Comment: Have you explicitly set `${HOME}` to `/root` somewhere?

Comment: @AndyDalton I don't set somewhere.It might be happen by any process.  Is there any way to reset all explicitly set env variable?

Comment: @AndyDalton thanks for your feedback. Finally resolved the issue. One background application write some env variable on /etc/environment file that override ${HOME} to root

Answer (score 1):

Given that multiple applications are looking for artifacts in root's home directory, that suggests that something has explicitly set the `HOME` environment variable to `/root`.  As a result, processes trying to process `${HOME}/.their_resource` are getting `/root/.their_resource` instead of the version in your home directory.

If there is somewhere that's explicitly setting `HOME=/root`, removing that should resolve the problem.